# javascript alert redirect not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I have an alert where if the answer is OK then it should redirect the user to a different page and if they click cancel they should stay on the page. But no matter what button they press it will redirect them to the new page. What is going on?

```
    <script>
    function validation() {
            if (window.confirm("Click OK if you have entered Anthropometric Data")){
                window.location.replace = "send_PhysiologicalMeasures.html";
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your `if`-_condition_ works.. Can you show us how you are calling that function?

Comment: Did you try with `location.href`?

Comment: onclick ="validation()" is what I'm using to call the function

Comment: Is that in a form? Please show all code context

Comment: What browser are you using to test this? Also, please post your HTML.

Comment: <a href="send_PhysiologicalMeasures.html">
    <button class="button PhysiologicalMeasures" onclick ="validation()">Record Physiological Measures</button>
  </a>

Comment: @Steve. The problem is your `<a>nchor` tag. Try removing it.

Comment: `<button>` shouldn't be child of `<a>` ... doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML button is wrapped in an `a` tag, which is effectively a link. `a` elements will **always** take you to their link specified in `href`, so just remove that `a` element: change your HTML to:

```
<button class="button PhysiologicalMeasures" onclick ="validation()">Record Physiological Measures</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to change the link's onclick to return the status:

```
<a href="/send_PhysiologicalMeasures.html" onclick=" return validation()">Link</a>
```

and the JS:

```
<script>
    function validation() {
            if (window.confirm("Click OK if you have entered Anthropometric Data")){
              return true;
    }
     return false;
    }
</script>
```

By returning false, you will prevent the execution of the link, and returning true will allow the link to work.

You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/am0adszu/